# Can I transit through Chengdu TFU airport visa-free?

Tags: transit-visas, china, twov, sichuan

I cannot find an official website stating which ports of entry are allowed. The closest one with a full table of ports posted on March 2023 includes Chengdu **CTU** airport (Chengdu Shuangliu International Airport) but **not TFU** (Chengdu Tianfu International Airport):

> | City | Exit ports | Scope of permitted travel |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Chengdu (Sichuan province) | Chengdu Shuangliu International Airport | 11 cities in Sichuan: Chengdu, Leshan, Deyang, Suining, Meishan, Ya’an, Ziyang, Neijiang, Zigong, Luzhou, and Yibin Chengdu Shuangliu International Airport |
>
> from
> https://www.china-briefing.com/news/china-resumes-144-hour-visa-free-transit-policy-for-foreigners-who-can-apply/

"Some websites" claim that transit through TFU is allowed, but that could be pre-pandemic information.

I'd fly Sichuan Airlines, but I'm not confident I can trust them to provide accurate information if I ask them. I'd like to see an official statement I can print and show before boarding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, TFU does have a *144-hour visa-free transit* desk.

I flew KIX-TFU with Sichuan Airlines and visited the clearly-labelled transit desk before going through immigration. Make sure you have a printed hotel reservation and onward flight ticket because they might not speak English at all.

[image: Temporary Entry Permit stamp acquired in TFU airport in June 2023]

References and helpful links for anyone landing here:

- in 2019 Chengdu started offering 144-hour TWOV (transit without visa)
- in 2020 TWOV ceased
- in [June 2021](https://www.shine.cn/news/nation/2106271175/) the new TFU airport opened
- on [March 15th, 2023](https://www.china-briefing.com/news/china-to-resume-issuing-all-types-of-visas-for-foreigners/), China resumed issuing temporary entry permits
- on [March 26th, 2023](http://www.chengdu.gov.cn/chengdu/c152802/2023-03/27/content_1bc44e3761a0452f852169aad0b52676.shtml) the first international flights landed at TFU

That last article from chengdu.gov.cn also mentions (translated):

> […] From March 26, China's civil aviation will start to implement the flight plan for the summer and autumn season of 2023. **All international passenger flights** originally operated at Shuangliu International Airport were **transferred to Tianfu** International Airport

> […] a special transit visa-free window will be set up to implement the pre-examination of transit visa-examination, optimize the setting of temporary waiting areas for passengers, and quickly handle 24-hour and 144-hour transit visa-free procedures for eligible foreign passengers

- The related wiki article on which you could find sources: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_mainland_China#Visa-free_transit
- The "National Immigration Administration" website mentioning 144h TWOV: https://en.nia.gov.cn/n162/n227/c58934/content.html

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, TIMATIC states :

> Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third
> country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit
> area of the airport and have documents required for the next
> destination.
>
> This TWOV facility does not apply when passengers arrive on a direct flight from USA, Guam or Northern Mariana Isl. AND depart on a
> direct flight to USA, Guam or Northern Mariana Isl. (JFK - PVG - GUM).
>
> Nationals of Australia transiting through Chengdu Shuangliu (CTU) or
> **Chengdu Tianfu (TFU)** with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a
> third country within 144 hours, starting from 00:01 on the day
> following the day of entry. They must:
>
> - arrive at and depart from Chengdu Shuangliu (CTU) or Chengdu Tianfu (TFU); and
> - have documents required for the next destination; and
> - stay in the administrative area of Chengdu, Lesha, Deyang, Suining, Meishan, Ya'an, Ziyang, Neijiang, Zigong, Luzhou and Yibin.
>
>   This TWOV facility does not apply when passengers arrive on a direct flight from USA, Guam or Northern Mariana Isl. AND depart on a
>   direct flight to USA, Guam or Northern Mariana Isl. (JFK - PVG - GUM).

Comment: Lovely, thanks! Can you add a link to that page? Assuming that the immigration at TFU knows about it, the next step would be convincing Sichuan Airlines at the check-in counter.

Comment: @fregante For the link, you can get a printout from the [IATA Travel Center](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/). The airline will look up TIMATIC, this is the world reference database for such purpose, and will find the same paragraph, but you can grab a printout for peace of mind

Comment: @fregante I am using an airline frontend to TIMATIC, indeed the ITC seems not to have enough control over the needed parameters, use the one from [Copa Air](https://www.copaair.com/en/web/us/timatic/) instead and make sure to input the airport code and not just the country

Comment: I definitely see it for Italian citizens on the Copa Air frontend @fregante. Make sure you inputted that as a *Transit Point* and not as the *Destination*, my mock itinerary was transiting TFU to go to Japan after

Comment: Thank you Nicolas! I ended up flying there thanks to you and all was good. I updated my answer.