Do I need transit visa for Chengdu Tianfu international airport for layover period of 12 hr 30 mins?
I am Nepalese citizen and hold Nepalese passport. I am flying from Tokyo to Kathmandu(Nepal) by Sichuan Airlines. I have a layover period of 12 hours 30 min at Chengdu Tianfu international airport (China). Do I need a transit visa?
Narita airport Oct 19, 2024 16:40- Chengdu Tianfu international airport Oct 19, 2024 21:00-
and Chengdu Tianfu international airport Oct 20, 2024 09:30- Tribhuvan International Airport Oct 20, 2024 10:40

No, you do not need a transit visa since you will spend under 24 hours in China. If you would like or need to leave the airport, you can avail of Visa Free Transit and apply for a Temporary Entry Permit at immigration upon arrival at Chengdu. It is free and routinely issued.
See bullet #1.
https://www.visaforchina.cn/CBR2_EN/generalinformation/faq/275556.shtml

thank you for your response. 12 hours and 30 minutes layover time goes from the Oct 19 to Oct 20. Will that require a transit visa since the layover time spans over 2 days?

You will not require a transit visa since the 24 visa free transit policy counts hours, not days. Since your layover is overnight, you may be interested in entering China (following the arrivals path towards immigration after landing instead of the connections path) to sleep at a hotel. For details on that, see the answer to this previous question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/181060/can-i-transit-through-chengdu-tfu-airport-visa-free
